# Bidirectional bind between a boolean property and two RadioButtons

Tags: java, javafx

I have a class, Person, with a boolean property named 'genre' whose value will
be true for a boy or false for a girl.

I need to create a bidirectional bind between Person.genre and two RadioButtons
so that when I person object is populated with data from a data source the
RadioButtons will be set accordingly (Male RadioButton checked if Person.genre
is true, Female RadioButton checked if `Person.genre` is false) or if user clicks
Male RadioButton Person.genre will be set as true, if user clicks Female
RadioButton `Person.genre` will be set as false.

Please, help me in getting the most appropriate practice with that: should
I use `Bindings API`, `RadioButton.bindBidirectional` method with
`Person.genreProperty()` or the opposite, or even use a change listener???

Best regards,
Romualdo.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
person.genreProperty().bindBidirectional(male.selectedProperty());
```

The other radio button will be synced with the `ToggleGroup`.